# preview/detail of single list on custom list view in android

Tags: android

I am new in Android and working on custom list view and it work perfectly , but the problem is when i clicked on a single list for show detail of list , every time it only show last list detail . within onItemClick  method only last invoice id is passed every... here is code

```
 try {

      //*** Getting Array of Attributes
            attributes = jsonreturn.getJSONObject(TAG_ATTRIBUTE);
            String status = attributes.getString(TAG_VALIDCODE);
            JSONObject invoices = jsonreturn.getJSONObject(TAG_INVOICELIST);
            JSONArray invoice = invoices.getJSONArray(TAG_INVOICE);

            if(status.equals("200")){
     // looping through All Invoice
       for(int i = 0; i < invoice.length(); i++)
         {


            JSONObject c = invoice.getJSONObject(i);

     //***** Storing each JSON item in variable
            JSONObject client = c.getJSONObject(TAG_CLIENT);
            String organization = client.getString(TAG_ORGANIZATION);
            String invoiceno = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
            String currency = c.getString(TAG_CURRENCY);
            String outstanding = c.getString(TAG_OUTSTANDING);
            String invoice_status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
            invoice_id = c.getString(TAG_INVOICE_ID);



    //**** creating new HashMap

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

   //*** adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ORGANIZATION, organization);
            map.put(TAG_ID, invoiceno);
            map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
            map.put(TAG_CURRENCY, currency);
            map.put(TAG_OUTSTANDING, outstanding);
            map.put(TAG_STATUS, invoice_status);
            map.put(TAG_INVOICE_ID, invoice_id);

  //**** adding HashList to ArrayList

            invoiceList.add(map);

            }
       }

       else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Details", 1000).show();       }


    }
           catch (JSONException e)
           {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }

     /**
     Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */

    InvoiceListAdapter invoiceadapter = new InvoiceListAdapter(this, invoiceList);

    mListView.setAdapter(invoiceadapter);

 //****** Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem

 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // getting values from selected ListItem

            //--String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();
            //--String status = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invoicestatus)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PreviewInvoice.class);
            in.putExtra("myinvoiceid", invoice_id);
            in.putExtra("uniquetoken", tokenid);
           //-- in.putExtra(TAG_DATE, date);
            //---in.putExtra(TAG_STATUS, status);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

My InvoiceList Adapter Class code

```
public class InvoiceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//--private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public InvoiceListAdapter(ManageInvoice manageInvoice, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> invoiceList) {
   //-- activity = manageInvoice;
    data=invoiceList;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)manageInvoice.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    if(null==data){
        return 0;
    }
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    if(null==data || data.size()<=position){
        return null;
    }
    return data.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invoice_list, null );

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.organization);
    TextView invoiceId = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.invoice_id);
    TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView currency = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.currency);
    TextView currencyvalue = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.outstanding);
    TextView status = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.invoice_status);
   // ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.invoice_status);

    HashMap<String, String> Invoice = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Invoice = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(Invoice.get(ManageInvoice.TAG_ORGANIZATION));
    invoiceId.setText(Invoice.get(ManageInvoice.TAG_ID));
    date.setText(Invoice.get(ManageInvoice.TAG_DATE));
    currency.setText(Invoice.get(ManageInvoice.TAG_CURRENCY));
    currencyvalue.setText(Invoice.get(ManageInvoice.TAG_OUTSTANDING));
    status.setText(Invoice.get(ManageInvoice.TAG_STATUS));


    return vi;
}

public JSONArray get(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-customized-listview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
              // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PreviewInvoice.class);
            in.putExtra("myinvoiceid",invoiceList.get(position).get(TAG_INVOICE_ID));
            in.putExtra("uniquetoken", tokenid); // Actually I can't find your tokenId in HashMAp object
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

Because you are referring a static values of invoice_id in `onItemClick()`, instead just get positioned `HashMap` object from adapter and using it key get values of `invoice_id`.

`invoiceadapter.get(position)` which gives yo a object for clicked position in `ListView`. And using key  `TAG_INVOICE_ID` from HashMap object you can get the values of it.

Comment: i have apply this code but get some error in my  InvoiceListAdapter class :(

Comment: When i use this line in my code invoiceadapter.get(position).get(TAG_INVOICE_ID)); it ask make invoiceadapter final i did it then get method is undefine for InvoiceListAdapter . when define it in InvoiceListAdapter it shows The method get(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: now i get this message "The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object" on .get(TAG_INVOICE_ID));

Comment: You can use this line also.. invoiceList.get(position).get(TAG_INVOICE_ID); Try this.. And look at my edited answer.

Comment: You can accepted this answer as correct if it solved your problem. This will help you and other user also..

Answer (score 0):

It is because your JSON object is already iterate to invoice.length() and invoice_id and tokenid which you are passing into Intent is content the record or value of last record. Move your JSON object on the desired position onitemclick and retrieve value of the variable from there.

Comment: where imove my JSON object ..please suggest me